# OBJC_META_CLASS Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, side-menu

Hi Team i am using following pod file in my single view application project

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'projectbase' do
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
# use_frameworks!

# Pods for projectbase

target 'projectbaseTests' do
inherit! :search_paths
pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'LGSideMenuController'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'MBProgressHUD'
end

target 'projectbaseUITests' do
inherit! :search_paths
# Pods for testing
end

end
```

But As i am using "LGSideMenuController" in viewcontroller.h i am getting the Meta class error following is the code and screen shot of error

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <LGSideMenuController.h>

@interface ViewController : LGSideMenuController
@end
```

[image]

Compilation with following line is OK

```
#import <LGSideMenuController.h>
```

But as i used

```
@interface ViewController : LGSideMenuController
```

error occurred

Can any one please help me to resolve this issue 
Xcode version is 8.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace pod file with following code.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'projectbase' do
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
# use_frameworks!

pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'LGSideMenuController'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'MBProgressHUD'

target 'projectbaseTests' do
inherit! :search_paths
end

target 'projectbaseUITests' do
inherit! :search_paths
# Pods for testing
end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.